# PyTorch Lightning - How to automatically reload last checkpoint when loss unexpectedly spikes?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm facing a problem where during training, my loss will unexpectedly spike, like so:

[image]

When this happens, I want to automatically reload the last checkpoint, reset the optimizer and resume training. How do I do this?

Edit: I tried training with fp64 precision and the unstable learning problem still occurred albeit later in training.

Answer (score 1):

you could write a [callback](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/callbacks.html?highlight=callback#callback-api) where you can check the spike and load the last checkpoint. Please, let me know if this helps!

Comment: Could you demonstrate how the callback can check the gradient magnitude and subsequently reset the last checkpoing (and maybe reset the optimizer)?